# Any suggestions on the design?

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I am trying to design a database using SQL Data Modeller, the problem I have is for my contract table I need to have `branch id` and I want to connect it to `branch rental` using a Foreign Key but this way would not work because `branch_rental` should not have a primary key of branch id` because this would not be unique.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: BranchRental already has branchID as the primary key. Are you asking if you can have table Contract as a many to many relationship table?

Answer (score 0):

Add a table named Branch.

```
BranchID
BranchLocation
BranchManagerName
...etc.
```